# jquery ajax post error 414 request-URI Too Large

Tags: jquery, ajax

i must send about 950 post params, but i have always error http 414

i try to use this code, but don't work

```
var data.param1="aaa1";
//.......repeat 950 times
var data.param950="aaa950";

var proccessData=false;
var type="post";
var dataType="json";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: "file.php",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        //dataType: 'application/json',
        dataType: dataType,
        proccessData: proccessData
});
```

also with dataType: 'application/json' don't work. all my attempts failed. I have read the various solutions but no I work

have you some idea?

Comment: Well the error is straightforward - as you've already seen - too much data in the POST request. You need to reduce the amount of data being sent. Why are you sending 950 parameters?

Comment: use multipal ajax request to send data in parts

Comment: inspect the request, sounds like it does a GET request, because the url wont be to large if using POST, maybe just uppercase it

Comment: it's a sieve filter with 300 rule (3 values for all rules)..i must send all

Answer (score 0):

the problem is into php.ini

max-input-vars = 1000

I was sending over 1000 parameters (chars > 35000), the apache.conf has always Directive LimitRequestLine 2000