# Submitted URI too large - using POST method

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I am submiting a ajax request using POST method and I had got the error 414: Submitted URI too large

I had already search a possible solution to my issue but I could not resolve the issue.

There is my ajax request:

```
$('form[name=editClinic]').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "includes/news.php";
        var form1 = $('#editClinic');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: formData,
          async: true,
          success: function (data) {
            var response = data.split("||");
            if(response[0] == "true"){
              $.notify(response[1],"success");
            }
          },
          error: function(chr, desc, err){
            $.notify(response[1],"error");
          },
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
        });
      });
```

The URL that is creted is the following one:
http://localhost/Repositories/som/administrador/noticias-editar.php?countryBanner=1&datepicker=1969-12-31+04%3A00+PM&highlight=1&typeBanner=Small&category=Tips&editor=FAMO%3ASWISS&og_img=57&title_US_EN=How+to+choose+the+right+chair%3F&subTitle_US_EN=Find+out+the+right+one+for+you.&desc_US_EN=%3Cp%3EWorking+in+an+office+usually+involves+spending+a+lot+of+time+sitting+in+a+chair.+So+how+can+you+choose+the+right+one+for+you%3F%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EThe+number+of+people+working+in+offices+is+growing.+Most+of+them+will+spend+a+whole+day+sitting+in+a+chair%2C+working+in+front+of+a+computer+screen.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EHowever%2C+this+position+is+detrimental+to+your+health.+Back+problems+arising+from+the+amount+of+time+spent+in+that+position+has+become+a+common+complaint.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EHow+can+you+avoid+such+problems%3F%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3ETo+avoid+the+emergence+of+back+problems%2C+preventive+action+must+be+taken.+One+form+of+action+is+to+be+careful+with+your+posture.+But+equally+important+is+the+choice+of+an+ergonomic+chair%3B+it+should+respond+to+the+demands+of+your+body+and+spine%2C+and+supports+and+promotes+good+posture.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EWhat+features+should+the+chair+have%3F%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E1.+It+should+be+adjustable+%E2%80%93+In+terms+of+sitting+height%2C+arm+length%2C+and+inclination%2C+among+others.+The+greater+the+adjustment+options%2C+the+greater+the+likelihood+that+it+will+be+compatible+to+your+needs.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E2.+Keep+back+support+in+mind%E2%80%93+If+you+spend+many+hours+sitting%2C+it+is+important+that+the+chair+accommodates+the+curvature+of+your+spine.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E3.+Take+upholstering+into+account+%E2%80%93+The+material+of+the+chair+should+be+sufficiently+padded+to+be+comfortable+for+long+periods+of+time.+A+leather+covering+is+more+resistant+but+a+covering+in+fabric+is+healthier+because+it+breathes+better.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E4.+Try+different+chairs+%E2%80%93+Don%E2%80%99t+just+read+about+features+of+the+chair+before+you+buy+it.+It+is+important+to+actually+try+out+various+chairs%2C+sitting+in+them%2C+to+see+which+best+suits+your+needs.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3ESo+now+the+next+time+you+need+to+buy+one+you+know+how+to+choose+the+best+one+for+your+health.%3C%2Fp%3E&idTrans_US_EN=37&title_US_ES=%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+elegir+la+silla+correcta%3F&subTitle_US_ES=Encuentra+el+m%C3%A1s+adecuado+para+ti.&desc_US_ES=%3Cp%3ETrabajar+en+una+oficina+es+una+tarea+que%2C+normalmente%2C+requiere+pasar+mucho+tiempo+sentado+en+una+silla.+%C2%BFExiste+alguna+forma+para+elegir+la+silla+m%C3%A1s+adecuada+para+usted%3F%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%C2%A0En+los+d%C3%ADas+de+hoy%2C+el+n%C3%BAmero+de+personas+que+trabajan+en+oficinas+ha+crecido.+La+mayor%C3%ADa+de+ellas+pasa+el+d%C3%ADa+entero+sentadas+en+una+silla%2C+trabajando+delante+de+una+pantalla.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3ESin+embargo%2C+%C3%A9sta+es+una+posici%C3%B3n+que+no+es+muy+buena+para+su+salud.+Comienza+a+ser+frecuente+el+aparecimiento+de+problemas+en+la+columna+por+causa+del+tiempo+que+se+pasa+en+esta+posici%C3%B3n.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cb%3E%C2%BFSe+pueden+evitar+estos+problemas%3F%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3EPara+evitar+el+aparecimiento+de+estos+problemas%2C+deben+tomarse+algunas+actitudes+preventivas.%C2%A0+Una+de+ellas+es+tener+cuidado+con+su+postura.+Pero+tambi%C3%A9n+es+muy+importante+la+elecci%C3%B3n+de+una+silla+ergon%C3%B3mica.+Una+silla+capaz+de+responder+a+las+exigencias+de+su+cuerpo+y+de+su+columna%2C+y+adem%C3%A1s+que%C2%A0+le+ofrece+el+soporte+y+promueve+una+buena+postura.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cb%3E%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+debe+ser+su+silla%3F%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fb%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E1.+Debe+permitir+ajustarse+a+su+medida+%E2%80%93+a+su+altura+del+asiento%2C+de+los+brazos%2C+la+inclinaci%C3%B3n%2C+entre+otros.+Cuanto+mayor+sea+la+posibilidad+de+los+ajustes%2C+mayor+es+la+probabilidad+de+que+sea+compatible+con+sus+necesidades.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E2.+Tenga+en+cuenta+el+soporte+para+su+espalda+%E2%80%93+si+pasa+muchas+horas+sentado%2C+es+importante+que+la+silla+acompa%C3%B1e+la+curvatura+de+su+columna.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E3.+Tenga+en+cuenta+el+material+%E2%80%93+el+material+de+la+silla+debe+tener+la+consistencia+suficiente+para+ser+c%C3%B3moda+durante+largos+periodos+de+tiempo.+El+revestimiento+en+piel+es+m%C3%A1s+resistente%2C+pero+en+tela+es+m%C3%A1s+saludable+porque+permite+una+mejor+transpiraci%C3%B3n.+%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E4.+Experimente%2C+pruebe+diferentes+sillas+%E2%80%93+no+lea+apenas+las+caracter%C3%ADsticas+de+la+silla+antes+de+comprarla.+Es+importante+sentarse+en+diferentes+sillas+para+saber+cu%C3%A1l+es+la+que+mejor+se+adapta+a+sus+necesidades.%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3ELa+pr%C3%B3xima+vez+que+tenga+que+comprar+una+silla%2C+ya+sabe+c%C3%B3mo+elegir+la+que+es+mejor+para+su+salud.%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&idTrans_US_ES=38&title_US_PT=%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+elegir+la+silla+correcta%3F&subTitle_US_PT=%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+elegir+la+silla+correcta%3F&desc_US_PT=%3Cp%3E%C2%BFC%C3%B3mo+elegir+la+silla+correcta%3F%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&idTrans_US_PT=39&cmdEval=editNews&idNews=16&bot=

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That looks like a GET, not a POST

Comment: The URL in your code does not match the URL you posted. Double-check where that URL is coming from. GET requests should not be that long, and POST requests usually do not have the data in the URL.

Comment: If you are really doing a POST getting 414 and as you have flagged php, maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186129/jquery-ajax-post-error-414-request-uri-too-large

Comment: why did you set the contentType to false? The default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` should be alright.

Comment: Servers can respond with an HTTP error if they do not support a certain amount of characters in a GET request. You may be running into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: Also, as previously mentioned, your URL shown in your code is `includes/news.php` , yet you show a URL for `noticias-editar.php` which one is it?

Comment: you probably need to update your apache or nginx to allow larger urls. i believe it is called `LimitRequestLine ` for apache